# prepend anything before a select

Tags: jquery

I just recognized that I am not able to prepend anything in front of a SELECT-Tag with ID.

```
$('#foo').prepend('bar');
```

on

```
<span id="foo"></span><select></select>
```

gives me "bar" in front of the SPAN

but on

```
<select id="foo"></select>
```

nothing is prepended. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you can only prepend an `<option>` or `<optgroup>` to a `<select>`. Ex: `$('#foo').prepend('<option>bar</option>');`. Anything else is invalid HTML. The [`.prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) method inserts the specified content as the first child of each element in the jQuery collection.

```js
$('#foo').prepend('<option>bar</option>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="foo"></select>
```

In your first example, `$('#foo').prepend('bar');` just puts the text `bar` as the content of your span #foo, and doesn't do anything with the `<select>`

Comment: `<optgroup>` also valid tag

Comment: @charlietfl true, answer updated. They're so infrequently used I rarely remember them.